# How can i press space every 5 min?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I want to make a application with a timer and on the event timer_tick i want my computer to automatically press Spacebar

Comment: What did you try? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: If you have an event that is supposed to trigger when you press the spacebar, then just call the handler manually.

Comment: so I made a form with a timer and a button. when i press the button the timer, which interval is 600000 ( 5 min) starts and in the timer1_tick method i want to tell my computer to press Spacebar

Comment: i dont know how to press Spacebar without pressing the button

Comment: i want something like key.PressButton(key.Space)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SendKey.Send()` method.

```
SendKey.Send(" ")
```

Answer (score 3):

just setup a timer and use `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send` method!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can platform invoke PostMessage from User32:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool PostMessage(HandleRef hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

This is arguably a better method, as it allows you to specify the hWnd and thus allows you to send keystrokes to windows which aren't native to the caller:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Sends keystrokes to the specified window
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hWnd">Window's hWnd</param>
    /// <param name="keys">String of keys to send</param>
    /// <returns>Returns number of keystrokes sent, -1 if an error occurs</returns>
    public int SendKeys(int hWnd, string keys)
    {
        if( hWnd <= 0 || keys.Length == 0 )
            return -1;

        int ret = 0, i = 0;

        System.Text.StringBuilder str = new System.Text.StringBuilder(keys.ToUpper());

        str.Replace(Convert.ToChar("`"), Convert.ToChar(0xC0));
        str.Replace(Convert.ToChar("~"), Convert.ToChar(0xC0));
        str.Replace(Convert.ToChar("-"), Convert.ToChar(0xBD));
        str.Replace(Convert.ToChar("="), Convert.ToChar(0xBB));
        str.Replace("{TAB}", Convert.ToChar(0x9).ToString());
        str.Replace("{ENTER}", Convert.ToChar(0xD).ToString());
        str.Replace("{ESC}", Convert.ToChar(0x1B).ToString());
        str.Replace("{F5}", Convert.ToChar(0x74).ToString());
        str.Replace("{F12}", Convert.ToChar(0x7B).ToString());
        str.Replace("{SHIFTD}", Convert.ToChar(0xC1).ToString());
        str.Replace("{SHIFTU}", Convert.ToChar(0xC2).ToString());

        for( int ix = 1; ix <= str.Length; ++ix )
        {
            char chr = str[i];

            if( Convert.ToInt32(chr) == 0xC1 )
            {
                _PostMessage(hWnd, 0x100, 0x10, 0x002A0001);
                _PostMessage(hWnd, 0x100, 0x10, 0x402A0001);
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
            else if( Convert.ToInt32(chr) == 0xC2 )
            {
                _PostMessage(hWnd, 0x101, 0x10, 0xC02A0001);
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
            else
            {
                ret = _MapVirtualKey(Convert.ToInt32(chr), 0);
                if( _PostMessage(hWnd, 0x100, Convert.ToInt32(chr), MakeLong(1, ret)) == 0 )
                    return -1;

                    Thread.Sleep(1);

                if( _PostMessage(hWnd, 0x101, Convert.ToInt32(chr), (MakeLong(1, ret) + 0xC0000000)) == 0 )
                    return -1;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return i;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SendKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx)
[Example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/64975c3d-f6c9-474b-81d6-86cfb1660fc8)

Answer (score 0):

You have to send a window message to the window focused window every 5 mins. So take look on SendMessage function
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx